# Flutter: My object list being filled too late in the code thus flutter complains must list is empty

Tags: flutter, list

My initstate calls the readFile() and that fills up my static candidates list.

Error:

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library >=======================================================
> The following assertion was thrown building Example(dirty, state: _ExamplePageState#77dfc):
> Assertion failed: file:///C:/Users/User/StudioProjects/flutter_card_swiper->main/lib/src/card_swiper.dart:164:11
> numberOfCardsDisplayed >= 1 && numberOfCardsDisplayed <= cardsCount
> "you must display at least one card, and no more than [cardsCount]"

But then right at the bottom of the console, my log message shows: [log] static obj len 10

So my file is being read and the objects are being added to the static list but it's only counted until after the error message is displayed.

```
  final cards = ExampleCandidateModel.candidates
      .map((candidate) => ExampleCard(candidate))
      .toList();

  @override
  void initState() {
    var f = ReadFile();
    f.readFile();
  }

  void readFile() async {

    final data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/qa_list.txt');

    final lines = const LineSplitter().convert(data);

    for (final line in lines) {
     // dev.log(' line : $line');
      final words = line.split('*');
     // dev.log('w1: ${words[0]} w2: ${words[1]} w3: ${words[2]}');
      final q = ExampleCandidateModel(
        index: int.parse(words[0].trim()),
        message: words[1].trim(),
        color: getColors(words[2].trim()),
      );
      ExampleCandidateModel.candidates.add(q);
     // dev.log('Cand object: ${q.index} + ${q.message} + ${q.color}');
```

Comment: It's hard to tell how your error message relates to what code you've shown, but your `readFile` method is asynchronous but does not return a `Future`.  There is no way for callers to determine when it completes.  If you depend on it completing, then you should make it return a `Future<void>` and use a `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

`cards` is computed **before** `initState`, when presumably `ExampleCandidateModel.candidates` is empty. After `initState`, its filled with some items, but that doesn't affect `cards` anymore.

If you are certain that you will not use `cards` anywhere before `initState` (for example, it would be fine if you only use it in `build`), then you can declare `card` with `final late` (or `late final`? Can't remember, but the wrong order may give you a syntax error XD), and move the actual definition within `initState` after your initialisation logic.

On second glance, I realised that a simple solution as above may not work, since the bulk of your initialisation function is async. What you can do is to either make `card` not `final`, update it after initialisation (remember to use `setState`), and in build check if `card` is empty. If empty, you can show a blank string or a hint message.

Lastly, if you really want to make it final, then you can continue with the `final late` solution, but introduce another boolean variable (*e.g.* `isCardInitialised`), which is set to true after you initialise `card`. In `build`, always check this boolean before trying to access `card`.

This kind of late initialisation problem occurs quite a lot in my experience, and while they work, I am not very satisfied with either of the solutions above. I'd be very happy for neater ideas!